# How to change value to httpd.conf from bash script?

Tags: bash, apache, automation, httpd.conf

How to automatic change value to conf file from bash script?
Machine: CentOS 6 and httpd installed.

Need change value of

```
ErrorLog logs/error_log
```

To

```
ErrorLog "|rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/error_log_%Y-%m 1G"
```

But automatic from bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's#ErrorLog logs/error_log#ErrorLog "|rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/error_log_%Y-%m 1G"#' httpd.conf
```